# Bad substitution for string passed as argument

Tags: string, shell, string-length

I'm writing a script that, at one point, needs to compute the length of a string to draw a box around it. I can't use `wc -c` for that effect because I will use it for non-ASCII characters (sad). I'm also avoiding bashims for maximum compatibility.

I'm using the shell's built-in string length calculator:

```sh
string="string"
echo ${#string}
# 6
string="stríñg"
echo ${#string}
# 6
```

So far so good, but now when I pass it as an argument...

```sh
_function () {
  string_length=$(${#"$1"})
}
# line 21: ${#"$1"}: bad substitution
```

Priting `$string_length` doesn't show anything as well.

What am I doing terribly wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's

```
string_length=${#1}
```

The variable is `1`, so `$1` or `${1}` get's the value of the variable. Then `${#1}` get's the length of `1` after expansion.